# C++ Arrays functions

Tags: c++, arrays

For the C++ arrays ( `std::array<int, 5> myArray` ) they have what looks like member functions if they were apart of a class. My question is, what are those functions

( `myArray.size()`,`myArray.begin()`,`myArray.end()`) called?

I want to research these functions and the others out there. It hard to do that when you don’t know the names of them.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Look up `std::array` on `cppreference`

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=We21AwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=bjarne+stroustrup&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw6afo74TdAhVRQN4KHWHCDx4Q6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=bjarne%20stroustrup&f=false

Comment: They're functions defined in the context of a type, hence they're *methods*, not functions. But colloquially people refer to them as functions regardless.

Comment: why do you think they (arrays) are not classes?

Comment: @Matt `std::array` is a type that wraps a "native array" - I suspect the OP is getting confused between a native-array and `std::array` and wondering why `.begin()` isn't defined for `char foo[100]`.

Comment: `myArray.size()` gives the size/length of the array in whole (bytes) in return type `unsigned int` while `myArray.begin()` and `myArray.end()` are iterators for the specifying the beginning and end of the array respectively.

Answer (score 0):

On [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com) you can look up many of these questions. In your case [it states](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

> std::array is a container that encapsulates fixed size arrays.

This means, this struct is a wrapper which allows safer access to the array values. It also has advantages in passing them to functions or returning them in functions. `size()`, `begin()`, `end()` are functions belonging to the array struct. They are usually refered to as methods.

`size()` for example returns the size of the array. `begin()` and `end()` supply iterators which can e.g. be used to safely access all values of the array without going out of bounds like so:

```
for (auto it = myArray.begin(); it != myArray.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see, you do not have to know the size of the array and you are still able to iterate over it AND be SURE you do not iterate out of bounds. That is a very nice feature.

However, I advice you take a good book and do some reading to get more firm with C++.